# Npm cypress: Using fixtures in foreach?

Tags: cypress

I like to use cypress for frontend testing, but after writing a lot of very simple tests I try to overwork it.

I defined fixtures in `cypress/fixtures/login.json` and `initialize` it with `cy.fixture("login").as("login)` in `beforeEach()` section to use it as 'this.login.KEY' in it() section. Is runs perfect.

But it is possible to use these fixtures directly in `beforeEach()` section?

Example:

```
context('description one', function() {
    beforeEach(function(){
        cy.fixture("login").as("login");
        -> here I would like to use fixture like
        -> cy.visit("/");
        -> cy.get('#password').type(this.login.password);
    });
    it('sub-description', function() {
        cy.get(#firstName).type(this.login.userFirstName);
         ...
    })
});
```

Comment: It should be.  Have you tried to do this and it didn't work?  Post your code.

Comment: I've add an example for better explanation. Still not working

Answer (score 0):

I've also had trouble with `this.myFixture` not working.  Try using it like this:

```
context('description one', function() {
    beforeEach(function(){
        cy.fixture("login").then(login => {
            cy.visit("/");
            cy.get('#password').type(login.password);
    });
    it('sub-description', function() {
        cy.fixture("login").then(login => {
            cy.get(#firstName).type(login.userFirstName);
         ...
    })
});
```

Comment: Runs perfect. Thanks to Brendan! Hero of the day!